# EF Core migration to remote database

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I have a working app and database locally. I want to setup a remote database for the remote application.

I thought forcing the environment variable would to it:

```
dotnet ef database update -- --environment Production
```

But it says "...The database is already up to date." Checking the remote database, it's still empty.

Now, the appsettings.json and appsettings.Development.json files appear to be working correctly. I confirmed my local application connects to my local database, and my remote application connects to my remote database.

Given that the connection strings are correct in the settings, how do I tell EF to do the thing again but for the other database? I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Are you running this command on a local machine? You must do this directly on the remote machine itself. / Take a look at [Introducing DevOps-friendly EF Core Migration Bundles](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-devops-friendly-ef-core-migration-bundles/) - several different ways of performing migrations are described here.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov with the connection string defined it's possible to do this from a local machine through the DB connection. I was just using the wrong environment variable declaration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was just using the wrong environment declaration. Run this before the update:

```
$env:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = 'Production'
```